# How to return 01 transaction number every year

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to return the transaction number 01 every year but failed. This is the procedure that I use.

Find the last number transaction:

```
SELECT   COUNT (NOKAS) AS JUMLAH
  INTO   V_JML_RECORD
  FROM   D_MSTHEADER_UKERJA
 WHERE   KTRASL = V_KDKTR;
```

Each transaction adds +1 to NOKAS:

```
IF ( V_JML_RECORD = 0)
THEN
   V_JML_RECORD := 1;
ELSE
   V_JML_RECORD := V_JML_RECORD + 1;
END IF;

V_NOKAS := V_JML_RECORD;
IF LENGTH (V_JML_RECORD) = 1
THEN
    V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON := '000' || V_JML_RECORD;
END IF;
IF LENGTH (V_JML_RECORD) = 2
THEN
    V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON := '00' || V_JML_RECORD;
END IF;
IF LENGTH (V_JML_RECORD) = 3
THEN
    V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON := '0' || V_JML_RECORD;
END IF;
IF LENGTH (V_JML_RECORD) = 4
THEN
    V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON := V_JML_RECORD;
END IF;
```

Format Number transaction:

```
      || P_BULANTHNSKRG (MMYY)
      || '-'
      || V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON
      || '-'
      || 'PK';
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'failed' - does you get a compilation error, or a runtime error, or wrong results? You seem to be making this much more complicated than it needs to be; but what does `P_BULANTHNSKRG (MMYY)` supposed to be doing? That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `IF` logic for this part:

```
IF ( V_JML_RECORD = 0)
THEN
    V_JML_RECORD := 1;
ELSE
    V_JML_RECORD := V_JML_RECORD + 1;
END IF;
```

as the second branch will handle zero anyway; so you can just do a single statement:

```
V_JML_RECORD := V_JML_RECORD + 1;
```

Then your logic to prepend a varying number of zeros can be replaced with a single formatting command:

```
V_NOKAS := TO_CHAR(V_JML_RECORD, 'FM0000');
```

The four zeros in the format model mean the number 1 becomes the string '0001', with the `FM` format modifier suppressing a leading spaces you'd get by default to allow for a nominal +/- sign.

You could do all of that in a query too, depending on whether you need the original value or are only using it to calculate your final string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(COUNT(NOKAS) + 1), 'FM0000')
INTO V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON
FROM D_MSTHEADER_UKERJA
WHERE KTRASL = V_KDKTR;
```

or if you need the intermediate values for other things you can get them all:

```
SELECT COUNT(NOKAS), COUNT(NOKAS) + 1, TO_CHAR(COUNT(NOKAS) + 1), 'FM0000')
INTO V_JML_RECORD, V_NOKAS, V_NOKAS_SBL_REKON
FROM D_MSTHEADER_UKERJA
WHERE KTRASL = V_KDKTR;
```

Comment: then how do you return the transaction number every year?

if in 2018 the transaction number is last 100 and when 01/01/2019 the transaction number becomes 01